# -daystart: unknown primary or operator

Tags: bash

I am following up with this error:

```
-daystart: unknown primary or operator
```

When attempting [GNU: Find.html - Age Ranges](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Age-Ranges:%7E:text=find%20%7E/%20%2Ddaystart%20%2Dtype%20f%20%2Dmtime%201) on,

```
find ~/ -daystart -type f -mtime 1
```

Does this option not work or is it system specific?

```
macOs 12.6
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0)
```

Comment: What output do you get from `find --version`?

Comment: Cannot see the option in macOS online manual. One alternative is to create a timestamp file like `touch -t 202301165959.59 /tmp/myStamp` and use `find ~/ ! -newer /tmp/myStamp`.

Comment: `-daystart` is likely GNU-specific, the tools on macOS are FreeBSD-based (or something like that anyway)